# The “of-a-has” system: Is “has” a logical operator?

Tags: reference-request, logic

Given that Mary is the wife OF John, it follows that Mary is A wife and that John HAS a wife. The same “of-a-has” pattern appears in most of-phrases, files, sets, networks and formalized natural language. Where can I look this up?

Comment: This is pure set relation considering possible polygamy having not much to do with logic at least in its generic and traditional sense excluding some other dependent types.